# Как можно отслеживать появление новых файлов на github с уведомлением в telegram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом я могла бы отследить появляющийся файл в ветке github, с уведомлением в телеграм бот?
В ветке, с периодичностью 1-2 раза в месяц меняется файл *.dt (* версия пример 1.0.6)

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://ссылка на файл')
```

Comment: Извините, пропустила этот момент. В месяц.

Answer (score 0):

Разверните локальную копию репозитория, обновляйте по расписанию и отправляйте уведомления хоть баш-скриптом, хоть хуками гита. Вот ссылка на раздел по хукам: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Git

Если есть доступ к репозиторию на гитхабе, то можно настроить события: https://docs.github.com/ru/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows